U-boot Loading Issue from SD Card
I am trying to boot an embedded system on the Beaglebone Black (BBB).  I'm using Buildroot to build my boot files and root filesystem. After setting up a boot partition with the necessary files on an SD card, I insert the SD card into the BBB. Using putty during the boot process, I can see the following output:
U-Boot SPL 2022.04 (Apr 06 2024 - 09:01:21 -0400)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2022.04 (Apr 06 2024 - 09:01:21 -0400)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
DRAM:  512 MiB
Core:  150 devices, 14 uclasses, devicetree: separate
WDT:   Started wdt@44e35000 with servicing (60s timeout)
NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from FAT... Unable to read "uboot.env" from mmc0:1... 
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Net:   eth2: ethernet@4a100000, eth3: usb_ether
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
Found /extlinux/extlinux.conf
Retrieving file: /extlinux/extlinux.conf
1:  buildroot
Retrieving file: /zImage
append: console=ttyO0, 115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait
Retrieving file: /am335x-boneblack.dtb
Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x6123a0 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Device Tree to 8ffec000, end 8ffff64e ... OK

Starting kernel ...

I don't get any additional output after this, so it appears there is some problem to start the kernel.  In the partition of the SD card, I have the following files:
am335x-boneblack.dtb
MLO
u-boot.img
zImage
I also have a directory called extlinux, which contains a file called extlinux.conf.  This file has the following contents:
label buildroot
  kernel /zImage
  devicetree /am335x-boneblack.dtb
  append console=ttyO0, 115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait

Can you advise why U-boot appears to not successfully load the kernel? Any suggestions on how to get past this?

You need higher level trace. Also  stop at the uboot and use uboot command line to see devices etc. Check extlinux.conf too

yes, I want to try to get the uboot command line.  While connected using putty over uart, I am trying cntrl-C, esc, enter, during the boot process.  But I haven't found a combination to get me into the uboot console.

you need to tell it to wait for input

It is any key then

hmm.. I'm trying to figure out how to get u-boot to wait for an input.   To do that, I think I need to set an env variable, but I can't do that since I can't get to the u-boot command line. Can you advise further?

extlinux is a key

extlinux could be the issue, but I don't see what it is..

I found error.  It is in this line:
append console=ttyO0, 115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait

There should be no space after the comma, so it should look like this:
append console=ttyO0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait

Thanks to @gulpr for the hints.
